# gem install sinatra keeps fetching wrong version

Tags: ruby, sinatra

when i type "gem install sinatra" it keeps pulling 0.9.4 instead of the new 1.0

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
gem update --system
gem install sinatra
```

Comment: I tried this prior, and it still keeps pulling 0.9.4. Is there some sort of cache i need to clear?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning it off and on again?

```
gem uninstall sinatra
gem install sinatra
```

Or updating the specific gem?

```
gem update sinatra
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
gem install --pre sinatra
```

But that gets you the 1.0.b version (beta version, I think), not the actual 1.0 release.